# What does the lazy mode of webpack dev server do?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am running my webpack-dev-server with

```
webpack-dev-server --lazy --inline --progress --colors --port 8082
```

However this shows a 404 error in my browser when it tries to access `bundle.js`.

Everything else seems fine since if i replace `--lazy` with `--hot`, things work fine.

What exactly does `--lazy` do then?

Update:

Here is the webpack file -

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: [
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // "only" prevents reload on syntax errors
        "./app/main.js"
    ],
    output: {
        path: "./js",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader"},
            { test: /\.js$/,  exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ["react-hot"] }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show your webpack config file?

Comment: @Kote ok i added it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some debugging I found that in `webpack-dev-middleware` (in `webpackDevMiddleware` function) there's the following if statement:

```
// in lazy mode, rebuild on bundle request
if(options.lazy && (!options.filename || options.filename.test(filename))) {
    rebuild();
}
```

The `rebuild()` function is never executed because `options.filename.test(filename)` aways returns `false`. And that's because `filename` value has a slash ("/bundle.js"). So, I changed the `options.filename` regex to allow this slash and it fixed the issue.

I made a pull request on github: 
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/pull/62

Answer (score 0):

The lazy mode simply doesn't recompile at every change but waits instead the next Call to the entrypoint to check for changes

Comment: so then why is it not serving the `bundle.js` file at all? shouldnt it compile initially when starting up?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the difference between --lazy and --hot:

```
--lazy: no watching, compiles on request.

--hot: adds the HotModuleReplacementPlugin and switch the server to hot mode.
```

Also, find more information about HotModuleReplacementPlugin here: 
https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins.

Refer: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html

Comment: what does 'request' here mean? a GET request from browser?

Comment: Yes, It can be GET request for resources like images/logo/js and/or css files etc.

Comment: so then why is my browser giving a 404

Comment: hot mode means no reload - the webpack dev server script will not reload if you are in hot mode. So in hot mode, it is not sending GET request again. thats why you are not getting 404 in hot mode.

Comment: let me reiterate. I am *not* running in hot mode. I am running in lazy mode using the params shown in the question. but i get a 404 error cause webpack is *not* compiling when it gets the GET request from the browser. that is the question