# how to load .scss files on demand via webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, webpack

In my project I want to provide branding feature. For this purpose I'm going to include branding style in runtime. 
But I can't find the method how to do it via webpack.
I want to write something like this:

```
require.ensure(['./branding/**/style.scss'], ()=> {
   require(`./branding/${brandingName}/style.scss`);
});
```

Can anyone help me to cope with it?

I've also tryied `bundle-loader`it doesn't works for me too

```
require('bundle!../branding/' + branding + '.scss')(()=> {});
```

Comment: Webpack works fine cause it understand what dependency you put in your js code via require and get it...so have you tried to put the require('style.scss') in your js (or typescript) file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the lazy mode of webpack dev server do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960032/what-does-the-lazy-mode-of-webpack-dev-server-do)